# Is it possible to get the windows version from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking at getting the device that the user is browsing with, i.e. iPad or Android or desktop/laptop (Windows) - is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at [device.js](https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js?)

Comment: Answer: yes, sort of.

Comment: Do you want to get the device or the operating system of the device? Why do you need that?

Comment: Thanks, device.js seems the best way to go. I actually would like to know if the user is using a android (less powerful device) or Apple IOS, iPad or desktop

Comment: really I am only interested in if the user is using an phone, Android tablet, Apple phone or desktop/laptop

Comment: I would like to redirect to a new page if the user is browsing on an iPad or laptop/desktop as I am using more intensive graphics/scripts

Answer (score 1):

You can get the User Agent.
Take a look : 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp
http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/